# setMinDate(...) for DatePicker doesn't work when invoked a second time

Tags: date, time, android

I'm in a particular situation in which I have to alter the min and max date of `DatePicker` according to the selected element of a `Spinner`. Here's the chunk of code I'm using to switch min and max date.

```
private void switchCalculationMethod(int method) {
    calculationMethod = method;
    switch (method) {
        case METHOD_1:
            datePicker.setMinDate(new LocalDate().minusWeeks(42).getMillis());
            datePicker.setMaxDate(new LocalDate().plusDays(1).getMillis() - 1);
            break;
        case METHOD_2:
            datePicker.setMinDate(new LocalDate().minusWeeks(2).getMillis()); // This don't work!!
            datePicker.setMaxDate(new LocalDate().plusWeeks(40).getMillis()); // This works!!!
            break;
    }
    datePicker.init(today.getYear(), today.getMonthOfYear() - 1,
            today.getDayOfMonth(), this);
}
```

So, the `DatePicker` would get set up correctly the first time, problem occurs when I attempt to change the min date again (changing max date works). It would remain at the value I had set first. I'm thinking this is a bug. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a workaround for this?.

PS : I'm using Joda time api.

Comment: Any specific reason you didnt use toDateTimeAtStartOfDay() on your second setMinDate?

Comment: @Voidpaw None, it was a mistake while editing the question. I'm using a custom method for that now. Just thought I'd skip that part for simplicity. Corrected.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This happens because method setMinDate() has check

```
 if (mTempDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) == mMinDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                && mTempDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) != mMinDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR){
            return;
 }
```

Simple workaround is to set min date with different year at first, for example

```
mPicker.setMinDate(0);

mPicker.setMinDate(new LocalDate().minusWeeks(2)
                                .toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis());
```

It works for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why the hell that check is there, but this did the trick for me. Must've been an intern.

Comment: I was assigning `DatePickerDialog` somewhere else, to change minDate I had to re-assign `DatePickerDialog`. like `mPicker = new DatePickerDialog(.., ..., ...., ..)` then reset minDate and setMinDate. @Nicolas answer was helpful in reset.3.

Answer (score 3):

As said above, you can bypass the check by calling those before actually changing the value:

```
setMinDate(0);
setMaxDate(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

If you want to **reset** the minimum or maximum value to its default, you can use the following values:

```
setMinDate(-2208902400000L);  // Jan 1, 1900
setMaxDate(4102531200000L);  // Jan 1, 2100
```

Comment: setMaxDate(Long.MAX_VALUE); is not recommended - it will throw an out of memory exception on low memory devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
mPicker.setMinDate(0);
```

doesn't work for me.

Try to reinitialize the picker.

```
mPicker = new DatePickerDialog(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

first update setMinDate to 0 after then setMinDate according to you dateobject

mPicker.setMinDate(0);

mPicker.setMinDate(datepickerObject.getTimeInMillis());